# Issues in BlackJack Simulation with Loops and Counters

Tags: java, eclipse

Here's basically what I have to do. I'm making a simulation of blackjack, where it asks for user input. I haven't incorporated an if statement to make sure that the starting hand value is within 2-20 (aces are only worth 1 point in this version of blackjack, so smallest hand is 2 and largest is 20). Assume that the user's hand is in that range. The simulation number must also be positive. Assume the user puts in a positive number. The range for the random numbers is 1-13 with 11, 12, and 13 corresponding to a value of 10. I also don't know how to make the random number equal 10 when the random number is 11, 12, or 13.

**Errors**

The bust count is either 0 or matches the number of draws/turns in the simulation that have happened. The turn count either matches the simulation or is one more than the simulation.

Any ideas on how I can get the bust to count correctly?

**FIXED**

Check edits for what I did to fix it and an explanation that may/may not be correct for why it was wrong.

```
import java.util.*;
public class BlackJack {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Random r = new Random();
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is the value of your starting hand: ");
    int value = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("How many deals do you want to simulate: ");
    int simulate = console.nextInt();
    int turn = 0;
    int bust = 0;
    do {
        // draw a card
        turn += 1;
        int value1 = value + (r.nextInt(13)+1);
        if (value1 > 21) {
            bust += 1;
        } else {
            //draw another card
            value1 = value1 + (r.nextInt(13)+1);
            if (value1 > 21) {
                bust += 1;
            }
        }
    } while (turn <= simulate);
    System.out.println(bust);
    System.out.println(turn);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you supposed to be changing rand every draw? Because right now it is staying the same every time a card is drawn..

Comment: I just saw that when I was looking back at my code. Let me change that and see if I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: code works now. Thanks for pointing that out for me. I didn't know that you couldn't set a variable equal to the output of the next random integer and it not be a different random integer each time.

Comment: No problem, anytime XD